# What is the required type argument?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

error TS2314: Generic type 'Type' requires 1 type argument(s) while upgrading ionic 2.1.0 in my app.component.ts page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the required type argument?

When something needs a generic and isn't provided. E.g.

```
class Foo<T>{
    data:T
}

class Bar extends Foo { } // Missing generic argument
```

## Fix

Provide the generic argument e.g.

```
class Foo<T>{
    data:T
}

class Bar extends Foo<number> { }
```

Comment: `public rootPage: Type<string>;
  public pages: Array<{title: string, component: Type<string>}>` What i want to give instead of string?

Comment: ` **this.rootPage** = DashboardPage;
    this.initializeApp();
    **this.pages** = [
      { 'title': 'Dashboard', component: DashboardPage }'.   I have an error in that bold part if i put the argument as string.